# Google App Engine - Libraries - "latest"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

The third party libraries and for Google App Engine using Python are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

I am unclear as to what version "latest" refers too. Does it refer to the latest version listed or the latest version released. For example, the supported versions for Jinja2 are "2.6" and "latest". However Jinja has released [version 2.7.2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/changelog/#version-2-7-2). Does "latest" refer to 2.7.2 and will update to 2.8 when it is released by Jinja, or does "latest" refer to "2.6" and will only update to a newer version when when App Engine announces there support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the latest version that GAE has made available in their library.  They do not always have the latest releases available immediately.